# unwanted text artefact

Tags: errors, external-files

There is this unwanted text in my pdf result.
I do not where it comes from.
[image]

there is nothing related with that text in my code.
[image]

can someone help me with this?

Comment: There is something wrong with your document/template that seems to be printing the name of the auxiliary file.  Please, show us a compilable document that demonstrates the problem (for example, by making a copy of your document and removing text and things that do not affect the reproducibility of the problem)

Comment: Please fix your question so that it shows the input that you actually used, and the error message that you got

Answer (score 3):

During creating MWE to recreate the problem, I found the source of the error.

In chapter 3, I want to refer to a figure from chapter 2 which is in another file.
I put this at the very top of chapter 3:

```
\externaldocument{08_circuit simulation} --> artefact
```

Without underscore, it leads to the issue I posted.
So the solution is:
Use underscore to connect words in the file name.

```
\externaldocument{08_circuit_simulation} --> no artefact
```

Comment: No, this answer is wrong.  externaldocument has no special handling for underscore, the filename must have an underscore not a space. You must have had a file not found error the printed pdf is not intended to be usable after an error. Also no one could have answered this as you made no mention of external docuemnt  the code you show does nor even mention you has a \ref.  `\external` document should in any case be in the docuemnt preamble, not in the chapter file.

Comment: I tried it again and the problem recreates. any idea how to make MWE for this?